# backupexec 12.5 not following symlinks on linux agent

Tags: linux, backup, backupexec

Ok, we are at a loss here trying to backup a linux box to a backupexec server...

we got a backupexec 12.5 server and a "backupexec for windows servers linux agent" (*sigh*) running on one of our linux boxes.

When a backup runs, we get exceptions reported for our symbolic links. it says something like:

> **BACKUP- \\<servername>\[ROOT]**
>   File
>   **\\<servername>\[ROOT]/<foldername>/<symlink>** is in the backup selection list but was not found.

Looking at the selection list, the symlink shows as a 1k file on BUE.

**Tools->Options->Backup** has **Backup files and directories by following symbolic links/junction points** selected. These same checkboxes are selected on the **Job Setup->Job Properties->Edit Template->Advanced**

Additionally, all the checkboxes are checkeced on **Tools->Options->Linux, Unix, and Macintosh** and on the **Job Set->Job Properties->Edit Template->Linux, Unix, and Macintosh**. These checkboxes read: "Preserve change time", "Follow local mount points", "Follow remote mount points", "Backup contents of soft-linked directories" and "Lock remote files", but apparently changing those options produce the same result.

Any help on how to get BUE to make a proper backup would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any specific errors in the BU Exec log?  Usually they have some kind of ID number? Any events on the Linux box that might point to a security or other issue?

Comment: I don't have this info right now, but will get it tomorrow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this tool, but I really dislike the syntax of your second link which mixes slash and backslash. Is this line supposed to be used directly by the linux system ?

You can also add a trailing slash to your second line and try again.

Comment: i don't like that either, i just copied the error message as it appeared, adding the placeholders for server and folder names. i also don't like to run something called "backupexec for windows servers linux agent" on my linux servers, which is definitely not engineered to run natively in linux... but BUE is what my employer uses for their windows boxes.